# "Not permitted to perform create on holds"

Tags: payment-gateway, balanced-payments

I can create a card and create an account with that new card, but when I try to create a hold I receive a 401 error saying `Not permitted to perform create on holds`

I am using `balanced.js` to create the card then sending the `card_uri` to my application.

I then create an account by `POST`ing

```
{
"uri": card_uri,
"email_address":"xxx@yyy.com"
}
```

to `https://api.balancedpayments.com/v1/marketplaces/MYTESTMARKETURI/accounts?MYTESTMARKETSECRETKEY` and I recieve a response like this:

```
{
"holds_uri": "/v1/marketplaces/MYTESTMARKETURI/accounts/AC6uOkhFTsOMpvY8zAvjnBtu/holds",
"name": null,
"roles": [],
"created_at": ...,
"uri": ...,
"bank_accounts_uri": ...,
"refunds_uri": ...,
"meta": {},
"debits_uri": ..,
"transactions_uri": ...,
"email_address": "xxx@yyy.com",
"id": "AC6uOkhFTsOMpvY8zAvjnBtu",
"credits_uri": ...,
"cards_uri": ...
}
```

and the new account with the new card shows up in my dashboard on [balancedpayments.com](http://www.balancedpayments.com).

When I try to create a hold by `POST`ing

```
{
"amount": 200
}
```

to `https://api.balancedpayments.com/v1/marketplaces/MYTESTMARKETURI/accounts/AC6uOkhFTsOMpvY8zAvjnBtu/holds?MYTESTMARKETSECRETKEY` I receive the following error:

```
{
"status": "Unauthorized",
"category_code": "authentication-required",
"category_type": "permission",
"description": "Not permitted to perform create on holds. Your request id is OHMf82dbd8e10a811e29f5d026ba7d31e6f.",
"request_id": "OHMf82dbd8e10a811e29f5d026ba7d31e6f",
"status_code": 401
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I create a hold using the BalancedPayments.com REST API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**401** means you are not authenticating when making the create hold request.

Instead of including *MYTESTMARKETSECRETKEY* in the query string you need to use a [Basic Auth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) header.

I'm not sure which of the balanced clients you are using (they include that header for you, you just tell it your *MYTESTMARKETSECRETKEY*) but for curl the request would be:

```
curl -u MYTESTMARKETSECRETKEY: https://api.balancedpayments.com/v1/marketplaces
/MYTESTMARKETURI/accounts/AC6uOkhFTsOMpvY8zAvjnBtu/holds -x POST -d amount=200
```

And the response looks like:

```
{
  "account": {
    "holds_uri": "/v1/marketplaces/MKxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/accounts/ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/holds", 
    "name": "xxxx",
    "roles": [
      "buyer"
    ], 
    "created_at": "2012-07-28T23:12:15.859231Z", 
    "uri": "/v1/marketplaces/MKxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/accounts/ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
    "bank_accounts_uri": "/v1/marketplaces/MKxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/accounts/ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/bank_accounts", 
    "refunds_uri": "/v1/marketplaces/MKxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/accounts/ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/refunds", 
    "meta": {}, 
    "debits_uri": "/v1/marketplaces/MKxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/accounts/ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/debits", 
    "transactions_uri": "/v1/marketplaces/MKxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/accounts/ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/transactions", 
    "email_address": "xxxxxxxx@xxxxxx.com", 
    "id": "ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
    "credits_uri": "/v1/marketplaces/MKxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/accounts/ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/credits", 
    "cards_uri": "/v1/marketplaces/MKxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/accounts/ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/cards"
  }, 
  "fee": 35, 
  "description": null, 
  "amount": 123, 
  "created_at": "2012-10-08T05:23:20.943961Z", 
  "uri": "/v1/marketplaces/MKxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/holds/HLxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
  "expires_at": "2012-10-15T05:23:20.876214Z", 
  "source": {
    "card_type": "xxxx"
    "hash": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
    "country_code": "USA", 
    "expiration_year": xxxx, 
    "created_at": "2012-09-03T01:08:31.530261Z", 
    "brand": "xxxx",
    "uri": "/v1/marketplaces/MKxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/accounts/ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/cards/CCxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
    "expiration_month": x, 
    "is_valid": true, 
    "meta": {}, 
    "last_four": "xxxx", 
    "postal_code": "xxxxx", 
    "id": "CCxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
    "street_address": "xxxxxxxxxxx", 
    "name": "xxxxxxxxx"
  }, 
  "transaction_number": "HLxxx-xxx-xxxx", 
  "meta": {}, 
  "is_void": false, 
  "debit": null, 
  "id": "HLxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```